# What's the purpose of \CharacterTable?

Tags: document-classes

I've been browsing some class files and many of them have a (commented) `\CharacterTable` at the begin. What is the purpose of this table?

Example of such a table from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HongjianLi/tex/master/BMC/bmcart.cls :

```
%% \CharacterTable
%%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
```

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks a great deal for finding the solution so quickly!

Comment: You're welcome :-) Once I had that doubt myself, so it was easy to find. I improved the title of the duplicated question so that it's easier to find in the future.